# Scala Constructor Deprecation

Tags: scala, constructor, annotations, deprecated

I have a class in Scala, which is currently constructed in the standard manner:

```
class Test( int : Int )
{
    override def toString() = "Test: %d".format( int ) 
}
```

However, I'd like to move over to indirect construction via a companion object. As the library I'm modifying is used by others, I don't want to make the constructor private straight away. Instead, I'd like to deprecate it and then come back and make it private once people have had a chance to change their usage. So I modified my code like this:

```
object Test
{
    def apply( int : Int ) = new Test( int )
}

@deprecated( "Don't construct directly - use companion constructor", "09/04/13" )
class Test( int : Int )
{
    override def toString() = "Test: %d".format( int ) 
}
```

However, this deprecates the whole class.

```
scala> Test( 4 )
<console>:10: warning: class Test in package foo is deprecated: Don't construct directly - use companion constructor
       val res0 =
           ^
res0: com.foo.Test = Test: 4
```

Does anyone know if Scala supports deprecation of constructors, and if so how it is done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3388) seems to describe the solution:

```
object Test
{
    def apply( int : Int ) = new Test( int )
}


class Test @deprecated( "Don't construct directly - use companion constructor", "09/04/13" ) ( int : Int )
{
    override def toString() = "Test: %d".format( int ) 
}
```

Can't try it right now though.

Comment: (edited) That does work, but it's not absolutely ideal, since you get a deprecation warning when importing this class, since the companion object calls the deprecated constructor - any idea on a way around that one?

Comment: Are you sure? You should get a warning when compiling `Test`, but not when importing it.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of my particular case, where deprecating the constructor causes a deprecation warning at compile time due to the companion object using the deprecated constructor, a colleague suggested I provide a second constructor using a dummy parameter, and deprecate the one without:

```
object Test
{
    def apply( int : Int ) = new Test( int, false )
}


class Test ( val int : Int, dummy : Boolean )
{
    @deprecated( "Don't construct directly - use companion constructor", "09/04/13" )
    def this( int : Int ) = this( int, false )

    override def toString() = "Test: %d".format( int ) 
}
```

This works, in that there will only be deprecation warnings if the user is calling the deprecated constructor, but obviously it's unpleasant - does anyone have a superior solution?

Comment: The superior solution is the one already provided by Jens Schauder

Comment: But that's not really a solution in this specific case - it's hardly ideal to ask users to replace something which warns of deprecation with something else which warns of deprecation...?

Comment: I thought you had already acknowledged that it does not warn of deprecation on the client code (you only get a warning when **you** compile `Test`)?

Comment: `Unit` or `DummyImplicit` might be nicer to use for the `dummy` parameter, since they don't contain any information (`Boolean` contains a bit)